# How to upload multiple images in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to upload multiple images in Angular, still, I am uploading single images but now I want to upload max 5 images.
for the single images, I have a parameter called `attached_image` where a single image is storing, but here I want to upload multiple images in `optionimage` parameter.

This is  my **component.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-8  col-xs-6">
  <div class="file-upload upload-button">
    <input id="custom-input" type="file" (change)="handleFiles($event)" multiple>
  </div>
  <!-- <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageupload" (click)="resetCropper()">Upload Image</button> -->
  <span class="img-selected" *ngIf="isImageselected">
    <i class="fa fa-check main-content__checkmark success" id="checkmark"></i>Image sel/span>
</div>
```

the **component.ts** code below is for uploading a single image.

```
handleFiles = function (fileInput: Event) {
  this.imageArr = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', image / png','image / gif'];

  if (fileInput.target['files'][0]['size'] > 1024000) {
    $.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: "File can not be larger than 1 MB" });
    return;
  }
  if (!this.imageArr.includes(fileInput.target['files'][0]['type'])) {
    $.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: "Invalid file format." });
    return;
  }

  var file: File = fileInput.target['files'][0];

  this.extention = file.name.substr((file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)).toLowerCase();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.target['files'][0]);
}

_handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
  var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
  this.base64textString = btoa(binaryString);
  this.attached_image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.base64textString;
  if (this.attached_image) {
    this.flashMsg = "Image uploaded successfully!";
  }
}
```

Please your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After select multiple files you will have these file in `fileInput.target['files']` array. You need to loop thru and call for example `validateFile()`.

```
var files = fileInput.target['files'];

if (files.length > 5) 
{
  // Error max 5 files
}

for (i=0; i < files.length; i++) 
{
  validateFile(files[i])
}

...

function validateFile(file) {
  if (fileInput.target['files'][0]['size'] > 1024000) {
     $.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: "File can not be larger than 1 MB });
        return;
  }
  if (!this.imageArr.includes(fileInput.target['files'][0]['type'])) {
     $.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: "Invalid file format." });
     return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for  you reply

Comment: but here I want to set five image in optionimage parameter and single image attached_image parameter

Comment: Please I  have not found solution of my question so far ?